# Additional indent in input box

Tags: html, css, forms, indentation

In one of my input boxes, the placeholder text is indented significantly.  I have tried text indent: 0 and adjusting the padding, but still no luck.  How do I get the placeholder text to appear normally on load? :(

Here is the code sample http://cdpn.io/juHKI

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the white space between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/details/kBjIH)